# Ruby script to search a string and delete entire raw?

Tags: ruby, string, replace

I have a text file and I need to search for a string, if that string is found I want to delete entire raw containing that string and add a new raw. As for now I just try to find a string and delete entire raw. And the string I search should be given as an argument. 
Code I have as far goes here:

```
arg1, arg2, arg3 = ARGV

read_file = File.new('conf.txt', "r").read
write_file = File.new('conf.txt', "w")

read_file.each_line do |line|
write_file.write(line) unless line.include? arg1 arg2 arg3
end
```

But the output I get is as follows:

```
C:/Ruby/tests/replace3.rb:9:in `block in <main>': undefined method `arg2' for ma
in:Object (NoMethodError)
        from C:/Ruby/tests/replace3.rb:8:in `each_line'
        from C:/Ruby/tests/replace3.rb:8:in `<main>'
```

Another approach I try is the following:

```
file_names = ['config.txt']

file_names.each do |file_name|
  text = File.read(file_name)
  new_contents = text.gsub(/regex_string/, "new_string")
  File.open(file_name, "w") {|file| file.puts new_contents }

end
```

But the problem here is that the regex string finds only certan string and doesn't take all that raw. Maybe you have any idea how I can optimize this code for my problem.

Comment: Readers do not understand your question. Please edit to define `arg1`, `arg2` and `arg3`. It would be helpful to include a small example that includes the contents of the file (a file with just two lines, say), values for the three `arg`s and the contents of your desired output file. Where you have "raw" (including the title), I think you mean "row", but " line" would be better. Where you refer to "delete" and "add", say " replace" if that's what you mean. ("delete and add" could be interpreted as "delete the line and add a line at the end".)

Comment: Thanks so much for the note. I will consider this next time I post a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So include? expects to receive a single argument:

```
line.include? single_variable
```

Take a look here:
http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/include%3F

EDIT:
You could try something like this:

```
unwanted_array = ['unwanted', 'error', 'string']
read_file.each_line do |line|
   write_file.write(line) unless unwanted_array.map { |val| line.include? val }.reduce(:|)
end
```

Unwanted array could also be built up by doing:

```
unwanted_array = [arg1, arg2, arg3]
```

Comment: but they are in fact defined, if go like this -

arg1, arg2, arg3 = ARGV

puts "#{arg1}\n#{arg2}\n#{arg3}"

I get the right result

Comment: @MherHarutyunyan, I tried your initialisation approach in an irb console and it didn't work as expected. Have you tried printing the values of arg1..3 within the loop statement? What does it output?

Comment: Well, if include? accepts only a single argument, it is clear why it won't work for me. what else approach would you suggest?

Comment: Suggested something in my updated answer. This solution is by no means an optimized solution, but might give you a starting point.